# How to backup multiple partitions in one image and restore

Tags: hard-drive, backup, partitioning, restore

I have a multi-boot system(win xp, win 7 and ubuntu). How do I get to backup those?
Win xp and ubuntu 10.04 are on the same partition through wubi. And win 7 is on a different partition.
What software will I use to image those 3 os' and restore it in different partitions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Several free products are available that backup multiple partitions or entire disks.
Some are listed below.

[**AOMEI Backupper**](http://www.backup-utility.com/)
Maybe the best of its kind. Does [Restore with Shrink](http://www.backup-utility.com/articles/restore-system-image-to-a-smaller-disk-1122.html).

[**Paragon Backup and Recovery Free**](http://www.paragon-software.com/home/db-express/features.html)
Lots of options. Also does Restore with Shrink.

[**Macrium Reflect Free**](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.asp)

[**EASEUS Todo Backup**](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/home/)
This article shows how to backup multiple partitions/disks/MBR:
[Free Windows Backup Software Help You Backup Drive and Partition](http://www.todo-backup.com/products/features/backup-drive-and-partition.htm)

[**Clonezilla**](http://clonezilla.org/)
Very reliable and stable, but more complicated to use.

Answer (score 0):

if you have a WD drive (western digital) you can get a WD acronis true image thing for free, this is enough to clone disks, and create Images of partitions.
it is working equally well with XP as it is with W7 , i have no idea about linux.
i boot it off a CD, and everything goes as planned so far
(until i remove my WD drives and wonder why i used the free version :-)