# Merging 2 non adjacent partitions with EFI in between [Windows]

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning

I have 2 partitions, one of which is unallocated, that I want to merge. Unfortunately, there is an EFI partition in between the two. Is there any way to merge these two partitions together without destroying my ability to boot?

That 750mb one is labeled as (EFI boot partition).

[image]

Comment: Unallocated areas are not partitions: they're the _absence_ of a partition.

Answer (score 2):

Use something like GParted LiveCD to move the partition elsewhere. The firmware doesn't care about the EFI partition's exact position (since that's always discoverable from the partition table), it only cares about its unique GUID. GParted will preserve the partition's GUID when moving.

---

(Technically, there is also the option of creating a *new* EFI system partition and deleting the old one, using Windows built-in tools such as `diskpart` and `bcdboot`. It's slightly risky.)

Comment: can I accomplish this via a ubuntu liveusb session? Is there a more detailed writeup on how to do this?

Comment: Yes, GParted is available on Ubuntu (or was last time I checked in 2018). Since you're dealing with unallocated space, just move the EFI partition all the way to the right (i.e. end of the disk).

Answer (score 0):

You only have two partition followed by an unallocated space.
To append the unallocated space to C, it must immediately follow C.
You may then use the Disk Manager inside Windows to extend C.

This means that you need to move the 750MB partition to the end of the disk
so that it will look like this:

[image]

You may use for that a partition editor. Examples are
[Macrium Reflect Free Edition](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree)
or
[Clonezilla](https://clonezilla.org/).
and some more are found
[here](https://superuser.com/a/141427/8672).

As with partition editing you take the risk of making the disk unusable, it's better
to take an image backup of the system disk using a product such as
[AOMEI Backupper Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html),
and to make a
[bootable media](https://www.backup-utility.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html),
and test booting it to see that it can see both the hard disk and the
backup image, just in case you will want to restore the last working
version of Windows.

Another tool is
[MiniTool Partition Wizard Free](https://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html)
that also has good tutorials.
Start at
[How to Move/Resize Partition](https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/resize-partition.html)

Comment: How do I accomplish the things in the last paragraph?

Comment: I added another free tool that has good tutorials.